# How to reuse JUnit Jupiter @MethodSource for multiple parameterized tests

Tags: java, selenium, junit5

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class Testing {

    String[] text() {
        String[] text = { "A", "B" };
        return text;

    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTesting {

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("text")
        void A(String text) {

            System.out.println(text);

        }

        @ParameterizedTest
        @MethodSource("text")
        void B(String text) {

            System.out.println(text);

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get:

`No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'.`

How can I get this to work? I'm a beginner in Java, so I'm probably forgetting something obvious

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to reference a `static` factory method via its *fully qualified method name* -- for example, `@MethodSource("example.Testing#text()")`.

To simplify matters even further, you can introduce a custom *composed annotation* that combines the configuration for `@ParameterizedTest` and `@MethodSource` like this:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("example.Testing#text()")
public @interface ParameterizedTextTest {
}
```

You can then reuse that like this:

```
package example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;

class Testing {

    static String[] text() {
        return new String[] { "A", "B" };
    }

    @Nested
    class NestedTesting {

        @ParameterizedTextTest
        void testA(String text) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }

        @ParameterizedTextTest
        void testB(String text) {
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Happy testing!

Comment: I think the `@MethodSource` would make a lot of sense with `value()` == `methodName()` and an optional `className()`. Would be a lot more intuitive.